# How to identify initial packet in TCP 3-way handshake?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, packet, packet-sniffers

Is it true that the `Acknowledgment Number` (please note I'm not talking about the ACK flag here) is set to 0 when a client initiates the 3-way TCP handshake by sending its initial packet?

I have a TCP trace file and I used the pcap library in C to print out specific information for every packet. What I noticed was that the `Acknowledgment Number` of the very first packet in a connection is always set to 0. Could I use that as criteria in identifying the first packet of a TCP session?

If not that, what other criteria can I use to identify a given packet as being the first one sent by the web client? Simply looking at the SYN flag won't work since when the server responds to the initial request by the client, it will also set its SYN flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *sequence* number will have a random value, but it is completely normal behavior for the *acknowledgement* (which you ask about) number field to contain 32 bits of zeroes in it.

This isn't to say that it can't contain data.  You rightly distinguish the ACK flag from the acknowledgement number.  The actual meaning of the flag is to signal that the value in the acknowledgement number field is valid.  Since it would be cleared on the initial SYN, there is no such claim.  As such, it can contain absolutely anything, though again, normal behavior is zero.

As to your question in distinguishing the initial SYN from the response, the response to a properly formed initial SYN by a normal IP stack will be SYN-ACK.  So, while the SYN will be set, the ACK will also be set.  To distinguish one from the other the better practice would be to look at the TCP code bits field rather than the sequence numbers unless you are trying to do some kind of anomaly detection.

Comment: No worries and no need to delete!

Comment: @DavidHoelzer But going back to my original question. What I'm trying to do by looking at a given packet is determine if this is the first one sent in the 3 way handshake. As such, will it suffice to check if the Acknowledgment number field is set to 0?

Comment: The answer is "Yes" but you should really rely on the SYN being set without an ACK.

Comment: The thing is that it is entirely possible (though 2^32 : 1 unlikely) that the acknowledgement number can actually be zero during a conversation.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer So in your opinion, it would be better to check and see if JUST the SYN flag is set? Is there any other instance when JUST the SYN flag is set in a packet, or does this only happen in the initial packet?

Comment: Never ever.  The only time SYN is set alone is during the initial handshake.  Depending on the reference you are looking at, you may see the top two bits in the high order nibble as "reserved" or as "ECN".  Either way, mask those two bits off.